# AndroidX.Test ActivityScenario: java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "STOPPED")

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, androidx

> ActivityScenario is a replacement of ActivityController in Robolectric and ActivityTestRule in ATSL.

When refactoring from ATSL to AndroidX Test, I am using this code to start my IndexActivity before each espresso test.

```
    @Before
public void launchActivity() {
    ActivityScenario<IndexActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(IndexActivity.class);
}
```

However, my tests are stalling out 80-90% of the time and throwing this error.

> java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "STOPPED")

When trying to troubleshoot, I changed the above to:

```
@Before
public void launchActivity() {
    ActivityScenario<IndexActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(IndexActivity.class);
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
}
```

However, I am now getting the same error 100% of the time.

Following the documentation, I am not sure why this is happening.

I am using AndroidX Test Orchestrator and testing on an Emulator with Api 28

Full StackTrace for Test here:

```
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "STOPPED")
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(ActivityScenario.java:228)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.moveToState(ActivityScenario.java:368)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at com.myapplication.android.test.HomeTest.launchActivity(HomeTest.java:30)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:76)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
10:54:42 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**: This is now fixed in https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/143

**Claim:**
There is a limitation within the `launch(Intent startActivityIntent)` method of the ActivityScenario API. It waits for the Activity to be `Lifecycle.STATE.RESUMED` or `DESTROYED` and if it isn't within 4.5 seconds then it throws this error.

**Context:**
My application uses an `IndexActivity` to load a config which instructs the application on certain API calls to make. However, immediately after it loads a `DialogActivity` and the `IndexActivity` goes into `STOPPED`. On accepting terms within the `DialogActivity` the `IndexActivity` goes back into `RESUMED` and then ActivityScenario works properly. With my tests, there was a race condition on whether Espresso could click through the terms within 4.5 seconds to get the `IndexActivity` to be `RESUMED` or whether this error would throw before that. It would take major refactoring to enable another Activity to be launched with ActivityScenario so that was not an option.

**The Fix**
Within `public static <A extends Activity> ActivityScenario<A> launch(Intent startActivityIntent)` of Activity Scenario, check the logic `scenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(State.RESUMED, State.DESTROYED);`

If you can create your own custom Activity Scenario and adjust this line of code to be something like  `scenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(State.STOPPED, State.DESTROYED);` then it will theoretically work for you. You can then use ActivityScenario again to move the Activity into whatever Lifecycle State you want.

**OR** just use the old https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule until Google addresses this in AndroidX Test.

**TL;DR**
This is happening because the Lifecycle.State of your Activity is not either of the two specific lifecycle states `ActivityScenario.Launch()` waits for, `RESUMED` or `DESTROYED`. Your activity is probably in the background of a dialog or another edge-case situation that was not thought about when creating the API.

Comment: Hey Mark!  Can this be accepted as the answer?  looks like updated androidx.test fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was because I had a device plugged in with the screen off and an emulator running. I assumed I was launching to the emulator but I was running it on the device. Since the screen was off, the test was never able to transition to a valid state.

Comment: Same to me. I expected the screen will turn on automatically, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this will be fixed in upcoming release.
https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/143