# FragmentScenario configuration - Binary XML file line, Error inflating class <widget> while testing with espresso

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso

Inflating error while trying to use `FragmentScenario` with `launchFragment` and `launchFragmentInContainer` if using material component in XML.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <widget class>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <widget class>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
...
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:886)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1227)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:710)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2063)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1853)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1808)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1685)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:554)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:308)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:286)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$1$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:534)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2093)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f03009f a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:538)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1214)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:117)
```

Can't inflate XML because there are missing styles.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all be sure to have the latest `fragment-testing` dependency:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
```

Some additional info:

1. The fix has been published in version `1.1.0-alpha03`, so prior versions will not work as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119054431).
2. Remember to use `debugImplementation` or the dependency will not work correctly, thanks to this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861706/2910520)
3. If you have errors like `"process crashed, "No tests found.""` check if this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128612536) can help.

After this you can create Fragments with:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
.... 
launchFragmentInContainer(bundle, R.style.Theme_AppCompat) {
    YourFragment()
}
//proceed here with espresso testing
```

> Don't forget `R.style.Theme_AppCompat` otherwise Espresso will crash
> with the `android.view.InflateException` error if you use widgets coming from the `com.google.android.material:material` artifact. Obviously if you need a custom style you can add a new  rule to your styles.xml and reference it here.

In my case I had the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) configured so I had to follow the suggestion of the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing?language=en#test_navigationui_with_fragmentscenario) to be sure the navController is ok with the lifecycle.

First of all I have create a generic method in my **TestFragmentUtils.kt**

```
inline fun <reified F : Fragment> launchFragmentScenario(
    bundle: Bundle?, fragment: F, navController: NavController): FragmentScenario<F> {
    return launchFragmentInContainer(bundle, R.style.Theme_AppCompat) {
        fragment.also { fragment ->
            fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { lifeCycleOwner ->
                if (lifeCycleOwner != null) {
                    // The fragment’s view has just been created
                    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my `YourFragmentTest` i can create another method like:

```
private fun launchMyFragmentScenario(bundle: Bundle?): FragmentScenario<MyFragment> 
    //viewModel factory can be easily injected if you use FragmentFactory
    = TestFragmentUtils.launchFragmentScenario(bundle, MyFragment(viewModelFactory), navController)
```

and call it before each test starts. (`navController` param is mocked in @Before method)

Comment: Yes you deserve thousands of reputation for this comment sir